# Codeigniter search with pagination error

Tags: codeigniter-2

Hello I have a problem with my search in CI. In the first page the results are displayed ok, but on second page it shows a 1064 SQL error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND cpt_echip.cpt_echip_nr_inventar LIKE '%%' LIMIT 10 , 10' at line 1

Here is the code (functions that are used):

MODEL:

```
function search($start, $limit){
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        $tip_echip = $this->input->post('cpt_tip_echip_nume');
        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (cpt_echip)LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_utl ON cpt_utl.cpt_utl_marca = cpt_echip.cpt_utl_marca WHERE cpt_echip.cpt_tip_echip_id = $tip_echip AND cpt_echip.cpt_echip_nr_inventar LIKE '%$match%' LIMIT $start , $limit");


        $rezultat = $q->result();

        return $rezultat;
    }

function num_filter(){
        $tip_echip = $this->input->post('cpt_tip_echip_nume');
        $this->db->where('cpt_tip_echip_id', $tip_echip);
        $q = $this->db->get('cpt_echip');
        $number = $q->num_rows();

        return $number;
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function search(){

        $data = $this->helpdesk_model->general();

        $start_row = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $per_page = 10;

        if(trim($start_row) == ""){
            $start_row = 0;
        }

        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/index.php/helpdesk/search/';

        $config['total_rows'] = $this->helpdesk_model->num_filter();
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['first_link'] = 'Prima pagina';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Ultima pagina';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagini'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['query'] = $this->helpdesk_model->search($start_row, $per_page);

        $this->load->view('rezultat', $data);
    }
```

VIEW:

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Nr. Inventar</th>
                <th>Nume</th>
                <th>Utilizator</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo anchor('helpdesk/detalii_echipament/'.$row->cpt_echip_nr_inventar, $row->cpt_echip_nr_inventar, array('data-fancybox-type'=>'iframe', 'class'=>'fancybox')); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->cpt_echip_nume; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->cpt_utl_nume; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <?php echo $pagini; ?>
```

Without the search and filter, the pagination works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It means the $_POST array is empty. There will not be anything posted when you navigate using links to the second page. You can pass the search data by url or store in session at first submission and use it.

Just check using print_r($_POST) to see what is there $_POST array.